# Use stream-browserify with expo

Tags: react-native, babeljs, expo

`stream` cannot be used with expo, as it is a Node.js standard package. However, the package `stream-browserify` can be used as an alternative in those scenarios.

In order to make modules resolve this instead of the native Node package, I am trying to make `babel-plugin-require-rewrite` work with expo.

I am adding this to `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      ["rewrite-require", { aliases: {
        "stream": "stream-browserify"
      }}]
    ]
  };
};
```

Unfortunately, it is not respected by the bundler. I get this error when trying:

```
The package at "node_modules\qr-image\lib\qr.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "stream". It failed because React Native does not include the Node standard library. Read more at https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq.html#can-i-use-nodejs-packages-with-expo
```

Is it possible to make this work in Expo?

Comment: Have you tried using `rn-nodeify`? (https://github.com/tradle/rn-nodeify) Seems like people use it with the lib you want to use https://github.com/tradle/rn-nodeify/issues/32

Comment: Didn't really work. I am not sure why, exactly. I created an issue with details: https://github.com/tradle/rn-nodeify/issues/77

Comment: If you're explicitly trying to use `stream`, newer versions of Expo already come with a ported `stream` version. Just go ahead and `var stream = require('stream');`. I'm using Expo version 2.6.14.

Comment: What Expo version are you using? Did you try to `require('stream')`? You don't even need to add it to package.json. Not all packages are ported. `crypto` won't work, for example.

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to modify babel config to use `stream-browserify` in your source. You can import `stream-browserify` in your `App.js`. I have created a simple example on [GitHub](https://github.com/StanislavMayorov/expo-with-node-package-example).

**App.js**

```
const Stream = require('stream-browserify');
```

**Package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "buffer": "^5.2.1",
    "events": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-browserify": "^2.0.2",
    "readable-stream": {
      "version": "2.3.6",
      "dependencies": {
        "core-util-is": "github:mjmasn/core-util-is"
      }
    }
    ...
  }
```

`stream-browserify` has dependency `readable-stream` which has its own dependency and use node environment. To resolve it you have to add these node packages. You can read about `core-util-is` fork [here](https://github.com/isaacs/core-util-is/issues/25).

Comment: Problem is, any module in my dependency tree that requires `stream` will still try to find the native `stream`, and not `stream-browserify`. I want to change all attempts to require the native module.

Comment: Yes. In this case It wont work. `rewrite-require` wont work for node modules too. Like workaround you can create `qr-image` fork and change several `require`.

Answer (score 1):

This answer [rn-nodeify install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633042/how-to-implement-aws-iotdevice-in-react-native/53778566#53778566) that i have posted should work. Except **Step 1** & **Step 5** follow all steps. **Step 3** is used for adding node packages you are specifically looking to install, in this case specify `stream`. Please do modifications in **Step 4** based on your requirement in **Step 3**.

Please do comment if you want me to elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

What ended up working for me was creating a `metro.config.js` file with the following content (I used `readable-stream` instead of `stream-browserify`, but I think either should work):

```
module.exports = {
    resolver: {
        extraNodeModules: {
            stream: require.resolve('readable-stream'),
        },
    },
};
```

And then I just used `yarn add readable-stream` and this allows dependencies to use `readable-stream` as if it were `stream`.

This was based on the info I found here: https://gist.github.com/parshap/e3063d9bf6058041b34b26b7166fd6bd#file-node-modules-in-react-native-md