# can not connect to aws iot device with react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, iot, aws-iot

i am building IoT app with react native.
used this package

https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js

but got error while running app

[image]

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, 
  StyleSheet, 
  Text, 
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';
import AwsIot from 'aws-iot-device-sdk'
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.connectToIoT()
  }
  connectToIoT(){
    var device = AwsIot.device({
       keyPath:'1d8bea736f-private.pem.key',
       certPath: '1d8bea736f-certificate.pem.crt',
       caPath:   'AmazonRootCA1.pem',
       clientId: 'IoTcloud',
       host: 'a3ckca0x6pesml.iot.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com'
   });
   console.log(device)
   device
    .on('connect', function() {
      console.log('connect');
    });
    device
    .on('message', function(topic, payload) {
      console.log('message', topic, payload.toString());
    });
    }
}
```

here i called this function connectToIoT when app is opened..
keyPath,certPath,caPath files are stored in root of the project

how to get rid of this error and connect my device to aws-iot???

already followed this solution from stack [How to implement AWS IoT(device) in React-Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633042/how-to-implement-aws-iotdevice-in-react-native)

but still stuck at this error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import Aws from 'aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk-react-native'
import AwsIot from 'aws-iot-device-sdk'

AWS_REGION = 'us-east-1' // Change if needed.
AWS_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL = 'us-east-1:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX' 
// Fill in.
AWS_IOT_ENDPOINT = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' // Fill in.

Aws.config.region = AWS_REGION
Aws.config.credentials = new Aws.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
IdentityPoolId: AWS_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL
})

Aws.config.credentials.get(() => {
const config = {}
let client

config.host = AWS_IOT_ENDPOINT
config.protocol = 'wss'
config.clientId = `client-${Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1)}`
config.accessKeyId = Aws.config.credentials.accessKeyId
config.secretKey = Aws.config.credentials.secretAccessKey
config.sessionToken = Aws.config.credentials.sessionToken

client = AwsIot.device(config)

client.on('connect', () => {
    client.subscribe('some_topic')
})

client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
    console.log(topic, message)
})

client.on('error', error => {
    console.log(error)
})
})
```

don't use the certificate that you are trying for connecting the Iot Device, use 'MQTT over the WebSocket Protocol' or
https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js/issues/86#issuecomment-371159865

Comment: awesome man..it's worked..
my mistake was that i didn't go through the Congnito Identity pool, that's why i didn't get accessKeyId, secretKey, sessionToken 
so now i successfully connected with MQTT with react-native..

Thanks once again

Comment: i am experiencing this error, error Event {                                              
  "isTrusted": false,                                      
  "message": "Code 1005 is reserved and may not be used.", 
}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is late but ill share this, I have also followed it and it was working!

He manage to make aws iot and react native to work together with AWS amplify.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EfbRKaPt2S4&list=PL8kT3V3swTBluh_HQ98YHrUacqZWCfmyU

Answer (score -1):

Your trying to send data to the AWS IoT Core broker? Also you have no topic in your program in which to publish or subscribe to messages

Comment: firstly it should be connected to AWS-IoT and my application is in react native..so during connection my app throwing above error